# How to run a project without dotenv?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-atlas, dotenv

I've created a Node.js/Express.js that manipulates a Mongo database through a connection to MongoDB Atlas. The thing is that the login to MongoDB Atlas info is stored in a `.env` file, which must not be uploaded to GitHub. So how will anyone trying to run my project do it without the data inside .env` ? I downloaded the project and tried to run it, but the app complains about the lack of the login to MongoDB Atlas info. The project is for a test to get a job in a company, so they will probably need to manipulate the database to evaluate my code. Should I give them the login info ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an .env.sample

Add ENV Vars there but leave them empty, so they can add their own

Answer (score 1):

You should never share your credentials.

The common practice is to share a "dummy" `.env` file with dummy credentials and instructions on how to edit it to point to a local database the user sets up.

If you want to go the extra mile, you could create a docker-compose file that sets up your application with a local mongodb container, and have the default credentials in `.env` reference it.